# Блок со стрелкой, который меняет положение в зависимости от положения другого блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть колонки на bootstarp. Между ними есть стрелки. Как можно сделать так, что бы при изменении размера экрана, стрелки вели себя примерно так, как показано на втором изображении? То есть, были привязаны к блоку и меняли свое положение/ориентацию относительно блока к которому они привязаны. Спасибо.

Comment: Каким образом у вас реализованы стрелки для широких экранов? Покажите код, и тогда можно будет показать исходя из вашего кода как их можно расположить для малых.

Comment: Ну они же просто по середине. Не понял, в чём проблема.